# Easier management of DOM creation of elements in PHP

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to find an easier way to create `<td>` elements and inserting text values into them.

There has to be an easier way than creating a new variable for each `<td>` element, right? Perhaps making a class with some abstraction? Or maybe I'm doing it the wrong way?

At this rate creating 7 `<td>`s will require me to  create 7 variables, 7 different `createTextNodes` for each of them and 14 more lines of `appendChild()`.

That will be 28 lines for only 7 `<td>`s. This seems excessive to me. Not to mention there's more than one `<tr>`in the table. Is there any way to shorten the amount of lines I can type to create something like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Short example code of what I'm doing:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;

$table = $doc->createElement('table');

        $doc->appendChild($table);

        $tr1 = $doc->createElement('tr');
        $table->appendChild($tr1);

        $td1 = $doc->createElement('td');
        $tr1->appendChild($td1);

        $td1_1 = $doc->createElement('td');
        $tr1->appendChild($td1_1);

        $td1_2 = $doc->createElement('td');
        $tr1->appendChild($td1_2);

        $title1 = $doc->createTextNode('This is title #1');
        $title2 = $doc->createTextNode('This is title #2');
        $title3 = $doc->createTextNode('This is title #3');

        $td1->appendChild($title1);
        $td1_1->appendChild($title2);
        $td1_2->appendChild($title3);

        echo $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the text to the elements directly:

```
$doc->createElement('td', 'This is title #1');
```

Apart from that, there isnt much to shorten in terms of method calls. DOM *is* a verbose API.

Answer (score 1):

Loops are your friends

```
$added=array();
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++) {
   $added[]= $doc->createElement('td');
   $tr1->appendChild($td1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/book.simplexml.php)? Especially: [simplexml_load_string()](http://php.net/manual/function.simplexml-load-string.php) which you can just pass a fragment of XML, and it'll convert it into an object:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string("<an><element>This is text</element></an>");
echo $xml->element; // => This is text
```

Doesn't get easier than that. Unless you just concatenate strings and [create a DOM Document from the resulting pseudo-XML](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.loadxml.php) to test if it's well-formed by checking the return value.